# Calling Visualforce Detail Page to implement a Copy of Custom Object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to implement a functionality to copy specific custom object in Force.com.

I was reviewing some ideas from Success Salesforce.com forum but I need more digestible thing than that:

This is my controller method to cp this object:

```
private Support_Order__c CopySO(){
    Support_Order__c SupportOrderCopied = new Support_Order__c();
    SupportOrderCopied.Support_Order_Owner__c = oldSO.Support_Order_Owner__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.RecordType = oldSO.RecordType;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Account_Name__c = oldSO.Account_Name__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Contracted_Account_Name__c = oldSO.Contracted_Account_Name__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Opportunity__c = oldSO.Opportunity__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Support_Order_Type__c =  oldSO.Support_Order_Type__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Current_Term_Start_Date__c = oldSO.Current_Term_Start_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Current_Term_End_Date__c = oldSO.Current_Term_End_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Extended_Support_Date__c = oldSO.Extended_Support_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Agreement_End_Date__c = oldSO.Agreement_End_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Client_Notice_Date__c = oldSO.Client_Notice_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Reason_for_Risk__c = oldSO.Reason_for_Risk__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Cloned_From__c = oldSO.Cloned_From__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Copied_To__c = oldSO.Copied_To__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Consolidated_Support_Order__c = oldSO.Consolidated_Support_Order__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Original_Support_End_Date__c = oldSO.Original_Support_End_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Do_Not_Consolidate__c = oldSO.Do_Not_Consolidate__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Opportunity_Owner__c = oldSO.Opportunity_Owner__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Status__c = oldSO.Status__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Sub_Status__c = oldSO.Sub_Status__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Contract_Date__c = oldSO.Contract_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Auto_Renewal__c = oldSO.Auto_Renewal__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Owner_Expiration_Notice__c = oldSO.Owner_Expiration_Notice__c; // Renewal Trigger days
    //SupportOrderCopied.Renewal_Dated__c = oldSO.Renewal_Dated__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Renewal_Month_Num__c = oldSO.Renewal_Month_Num__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Cancellation_Date__c = oldSO.Cancellation_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Cancellation_Effective_Date__c = oldSO.Cancellation_Effective_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Customer_Region__c = oldSO.Customer_Region__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Default_Escalation_Index__c = oldSO.Default_Escalation_Index__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Default_Escalation_CAP__c = oldSO.Default_Escalation_CAP__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Escalation_Floor__c = oldSO.Escalation_Floor__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Default_Escalation_Effective_Date__c = oldSO.Default_Escalation_Effective_Date__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Default_Escalation_P__c = oldSO.Default_Escalation_P__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.I_Agree__c = oldSO.I_Agree__c; // Calculate Escalation
    //SupportOrderCopied.Annual_Support_Fees__c = oldSO.Annual_Support_Fees__c;//data child object comes from the Support Order
    SupportOrderCopied.Cancellation_Policy__c = oldSO.Cancellation_Policy__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Payment_Terms__c = oldSO.Payment_Terms__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Billing_Status__c = oldSO.Billing_Status__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.PO_Notice__c = oldSO.PO_Notice__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Quote_Notice__c = oldSO.Quote_Notice__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Clone_Date__c = oldSO.Clone_Date__c;
    insert SupportOrderCopied;
    return SupportOrderCopied;
}
```

My question is how to display by the edit mode this object in salesforce.com using Visualforce page after cp functionality is calling through the custom object. I have a piece of visual code following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Support_Order__c">
  <apex:detail subject="{!getSupportOrder.Id}" mode="edit"/>
</apex:page>
```

Please any idea will be very useful.

Thanks

Comment: Just use the standard `clone` button.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson quick answer. My copy is custom func. It is able to copy specific custom fields. wsdl and web service can be an option.

Comment: So did you create a custom button and add it to the layout?

Comment: Yes @AdrianLarson I did. But now I need to associate my sObject with my apex method through ajax. I am getting undefined object from execute("myClass","myMtd",{object}).

Comment: why in the world would you use ajax? Make it a `Visualforce` button. It's a much more straightforward design.

Comment: I am only using ajax with javascript to call the apex controller to query the oldObj to the new one using custom page detail button not a visualforce button. I am not using visualforce code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom object should have a standard `Clone` button available. I recommend using that instead of rolling a custom `Visualforce` implementation.

However, if you want to use a `Visualforce Page` as a `Custom Button`, you need to first create the button, then modify your `Page Layout` to include it.

1. To create the button, go to `Customize` > `Cases` > `Buttons, Links, and Actions`.
2. Click <kbd>New Button or Link</kbd>.
3. Populate `Label` > `Clone`.
4. Select `Display Type` > `Detail Page Button`
5. Select `Content Source` > `Visualforce Page`.
6. Select your page.
7. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

Remember to add the button to your `Page Layout` once you are done.

Another note, even if you insist on sticking with `Apex`, you can still use the `SObject.clone` method. (See [sObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)):

> clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)

```
Support_Order__c clone = oldSO.clone();
insert clone;
return clone;
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy a Custom Object first thing to do is create the custom Detail Page Button in Javascript code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

var customSO = new sforce.SObject("Support_Order__c");
var soId = '{!Support_Order__c.Id}';

var result = sforce.apex.execute("SO_AutoCopy_WSController","CopySO",  {oldSO:soId});

if('{!Support_Order__c.IsAlreadyCloned__c}' == true) {
  alert('Already Copied');
}
else{
  sforce.debug.trace = true;
  alert('Support Order has been copied successfully');
  window.location.href = '/'+result;
}
```

then create a internal wsdl script in apex code to call this functionality externally from your s-control.

```
global with sharing class SO_AutoCopy_WSController {//using WSDL Class to store the Copied Support Order 

public static Support_Order__c oldSOToCopy{get; set;}
public SO_AutoCopy_WSController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    oldSOToCopy = new Support_Order__c();
}

//Support Order Copy Functionality    
webservice static String CopySO(String oldSO){
    oldSOToCopy = [SELECT 
            Id, Agreement_End_Date__c,Auto_Renewal__c,
            RecordTypeId,Status__c,Contract__c,
            Opportunity__c,Support_Order_Type__c,I_Agree__c,
            Sub_Status__c,Support_Order_Owner__c 
            FROM Support_Order__c WHERE Id =: oldSO LIMIT 1];   
    Support_Order__c SupportOrderCopied = new Support_Order__c();
    SupportOrderCopied.IsAlreadyCloned__c = true;
    SupportOrderCopied.Support_Order_Owner__c = oldSOToCopy.Support_Order_Owner__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.RecordTypeId = oldSOToCopy.RecordTypeId;
    SupportOrderCopied.Contract__c = oldSOToCopy.Contract__c;
    //SupportOrderCopied.Account_Name__c = oldSO.Account_Name__c;
    SupportOrderCopied.Contracted_Account_Name__c = oldSOToCopy.Contracted_Account_Name__c;
    //...       
    try{
        insert SupportOrderCopied;
        return SupportOrderCopied.Id;
    }catch(DmlException e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }           
  } 
}
```

Just to highlight every time calling from s-control or OnClick Javascript you have to recreate the properly structure for your goals.